# Background audio recording

Tags: ios, audio, background, audio-recording

I wish to record audio when my app is not active. Currently `AVAudioRecorder` works great for `active` mode of app. But `inactive` mode is unpredictable.

`AVAudioRecorder` can be used for `inactive` also? Any other class which could serve the purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `project navigation` select your app - > `capabilities` - > `turn on background modes` -> check `Audio, AirPlay, and Picture in Picture`

This setup will add `required background modes` key in your `info.plist`

After making this setup you can record audio in background by `AVAudioRecorder`.

You can refer screenshot below,

[image]